# Truffle contract interaction with async await

Tags: ecmascript-6, async-await, ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

I am using `nodejs` v.8.15.0 and `truffle` v4.1.15. I have deployed a contract and I can also interact with it, but not the way it is stated on [truffles page](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts)

Because if I do one of these:

```
let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
let balance = await instance.getBalance(accounts[0])
```

I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

The same happens using the package `truffle-contract`, even though there are also ES6 examples in the [github description](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/truffle-contract):

```
const deployed = await MyContract.deployed();
const result = await instance.someFunction(5);
```

Does anybody know why it is not working as stated in the examples?

Comment: It's literally what the error says and has nothing to do with Truffle - you can only use the `await` keyword inside functions marked as `async`. It is a syntax error to use `await` outside functions.

Answer (score 4):

When you use await, the function that executes your code should be marked as async, something like:

```
async function _your_function_name() {
  ...

  let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  let balance = await instance.getBalance(accounts[0])

  ...
}
```

You may also think to use an async IIFE to avoid marking the entire function as async, even if I am missing a good reason for doing it:

```
...

let accounts
let balance

(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  balance = await instance.getBalance(accounts[0])
})()

...
```

Here a more detailed explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function